# How can I efficiently index a non-square product matrix among n threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix

Suppose I want to use multithreading to multiply an i×j matrix with a j×k matrix to produce an i×k matrix, where i, j, and k are unknown. The number of threads, n, tasked with performing the matrix multiplication is also unknown. How can I efficiently determine the indices of the product matrix each thread is responsible for calculating?

For reference, my initial approach was to divide the total number of elements (the product of i and k) by the number of threads (n) to obtain the number of indices each thread was responsible for. As each thread was created, it passed its number (i.e. thread 0, 1, 2...) to the multiplication method to determine the starting and ending indices as if the matrix were 1-dimensional (i.e. [0][0] = 0, [0][1] = 1, [0][2] = 2...). Finally, the method would iterate through each 1-dimensional index, convert it to its 2-dimensional counterpart, and determine the value at each index.

This approach works but I am noticing that, in Java, it doesn't speed up matrix multiplication. In fact, it often appears to slow the process down as the size of the matrices increases. Assuming that I have properly implemented threads in Java, why might this be? I suspect it has to do with the calculations required to determine the 2-dimensional indices (in my case, two extra arithmetic operations per index) but I also know that there is some level of overhead that comes with implementing threads.

Here is my implementation in case the above description was not clear:

```
public synchronized void perform(int id) {
    int first = id * NUM_OPS;
    int last = first + NUM_OPS - 1;

    if(id == NUM_THREADS - 1)
        last += (i * k) % NUM_THREADS;

    if(last >= i * k)
        return;

    for(int curr = first; curr <= last; curr++) {
        int p = curr / k;
        int r = curr % k;
        for(int q = 0; q < j; q++)
            C[p][r] += A[p][q] * B[q][r];
    }
}
```

Comment: You said "efficiently", right? Then *"As each thread was created"* is contrary to your goals, because starting threads is slow. You should use a thread pool.

Comment: @Andreas This ended up working very well, thank you! However, I'm still uncertain about why my initial approach was slow. Perhaps my implementation was not actually parallel.